# Error in BOOT/BCD after I installed Kali Linux alongside with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, kali-linux, hp-pavilion

I am new to Linux. I tried it and I loved it so I decided to install one.

I went for Kali Linux. I installed it as per the installation guide described in this doc and on almost every other installation guide.

So When I finished, I started my PC and then this message appeared on windows screen.

**"Your PC ran into a problem"**
I tried to restart, reset and everything I could do but nothing work.

I also tried to fix Booting with **BOOTREC/Fix Boot, DISKPART** , but this resulted in errors as well.

Major problem is that, no repairing option is reading my Hard Drive. Below is the errors of the commands, I tried.

**bootrec /scanos 
Total Identified Windows Installation : 0**

**bootrec /fixboot 
this volume does not contain a recognized file system.**

When I tried to install another windows from the CD, the list of drives did not appear in the list.

I have tried different methods, but this is not working.

If you guys know any solution, please let me know.

**FYI, Neither Kali nor Windows worked fine after the Kali Linux Installation.**

Thanks,
Asma

Comment: I assume the bootloader you installed is GRUB? Do you see the choice to chose which OS when you bootup?

Comment: Hello Eric! yes it was GRUB.

I was seeing the choice to choose an OS right after I finished Linux installation but Kali did not work so I switched to Windows, but it did not work either!

Now, I do not see any OS selection option.

Comment: I finally just read that you installed Kali. I don't think Kali is intended for dual boots... Kali isn't really made to be a full OS but rather a tool. The better option would be to use a virtual machine or run from the CD for Kali. In order to fix your system, you can try and use the Windows repair options usually found on the cd or (https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader) follow these steps if you can actually get into Windows at any point

Comment: Actually it looks like you can do a dual boot but take a look at this article for the additional steps that should be done as well https://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows

Comment: I did the exact! Created a new partition to install Kali! But it messed up with Windows!
I have tried almost every solution, not working!
The thing is, my installations and drives are not appearing in scan or search when I try to fix by using different commands!

Comment: And that's why Kali is NOT for you. Kali is a professional tool intended for those with advanced knowledge, i.e., users that know how to install and troubleshoot a Linux distro, standalone or multi boot.